# Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::getContributionTokenValues()

Tags: civicontribute, tokens

Steps to reproduce:

- Search -> Find contribution
- Search for a contribution
- Choose "Email - send now" as action
- Choose an email template with a token. In our case we just use the token "{contact.email_greeting}"
- Send the email

The following error message appears several times for each email:

```
Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::getContributionTokenValues() (line 5769 of \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Contribute\BAO\Contribution.php).
```

We use CiviCRM with Drupal 7 and the latest CiviCRM 5.29.1.

For me it seems that the code

```
    if (strpos($fieldName, 'custom_') === 0 && array_search($fieldName, $messageToken['contribution']) !== FALSE) {
      $result['values'][$id][$fieldName] = CRM_Core_BAO_CustomField::displayValue($result['values'][$id][$fieldName], $fieldName);
    }
```

should be

```
    if (isset($messageToken['contribution']) && strpos($fieldName, 'custom_') === 0 && array_search($fieldName, $messageToken['contribution']) !== FALSE) {
      $result['values'][$id][$fieldName] = CRM_Core_BAO_CustomField::displayValue($result['values'][$id][$fieldName], $fieldName);
    }
```

because by now `array_search($fieldName, $messageToken['contribution'])` assumes that `$messageToken['contribution']` is set which does not seem to be true in every case.